# Assign scope variable from Asnyc factory call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a factory where I am pulling data from an API and trying to assign the results to a variable. Everytime I run, I get my variable is undefined. Any way in which I can pass the results to my variable from an async call?
For instance in my case. My factory looks like this.

```
angular.module('MyApp.services', [])
.factory('ReportService', ['$http', '$window', '$upload', 'AuthService', function ($http, $window, $upload, AuthService) {
    return {
        findAll: function (criteria) {
            criteria = criteria || [];

            return $http.get(BASE_URL + '/ajax.php?action=reports.all&' + criteria.join('&'));
        }        
    }
}])
```

then in my controller

```
.controller('MyViewController', [
    '$scope', 'ReportService', 'toaster', '$modal', '$rootScope',
    function ($scope, ReportService, toaster, $modal, $rootScope) {
        ReportService
            .findAll()
            .then(
            function success(response, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.reports = response.data.reports;
            },
            function error(response, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('error');
            });
    //console.log($scope.reports) returns undefined here.
    }
]);
```

How do I go about getting the variable populated at the global level for the controller?

Comment: Write `console.log` into `success` function.

Comment: You're writing to the console before `$scope.reports` is assigned a value. That's why it's logging undefined.

Comment: So the `console.log()` clearly isn't working as you're expecting. Are you sure that `$scope.reports` isn't being populated, though?

Comment: ReportService.findAll() accepts one parameter, and you are not passing anything.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure `findAll()`'s parameter is optional.

Comment: How do I access it outside the success function? I would like to use it outside the factory call. When I do place it within success I do get the values.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your variable is undefined when you call `console.log($scope.reports)` is because your code is asynchronous. Thus you're executing `console.log($scope.reports)` before the http request returns and causes the `$scope.reports` variable to be assigned with the returned data. This is just the nature of asynchronous code.

Here's what happens chronologically:

1. You call `ReportService.findAll()`
2. You call `console.log($scope.reports)`
3. [some time later] the promise from `ReportService.findAll()` resolves and calls your success callback, which in turn sets `$scope.reports = response.data.reports;`

As you can see, it makes sense that when you call `console.log` in step 2, that your variable is undefined. So your variable is defined/populated in your controller, just not at the point in time when you call `console.log($scope.reports)`.

Comment: Do i have to have the rest of my code under the then function? Was thinking it would be possible to use the scope.reports globally or outside the asynchronous call

Comment: If you're doing something with the value of `$scope.reports` inside the controller, then yes, you must do it at the point in time that the `then` callback is executed. This is pretty much how asynchrony works in almost all programming languages and frameworks; you cannot manipulate the data until it's ready. You can use it in templates, just fine, since the dirty checking of angular, makes sure to update the view whenever the value of the variable changes.

Answer (score 0):

By the time your service returning the response, `console.log($scope.reports)` is executing. Hence you are getting **undefined**

Please put your console statement inside `.then(function success(){`

It won't be an undefined and it will print the reports

#### Controller

```
.controller('MyViewController', [
'$scope', 'ReportService', 'toaster', '$modal', '$rootScope',
function ($scope, ReportService, toaster, $modal, $rootScope) {
    ReportService
        .findAll()
        .then(
        function success(response, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.reports = response.data.reports;
           console.log($scope.reports) // put it here // #2 won't be undefined.
        },
        function error(response, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error');
        });
      //console.log($scope.reports) returns undefined here. //#2 remove from here
}
]);
```